# Consumable items in iOS Newstand app that sells magazines

Tags: in-app-purchase, appstore-approval, newsstand-kit, ios

The issue library is implemented using "credit system". User can buy credits and spend them on individual issues.
The receipt verification and transactions are done on my server.

The reason why I did it like this is because I want offer same content over web site, so user on iPad/iPhone can buy/download/read the same content that on web. When he buys issue on web, the issue will be available also on iOS device.

The plan is to have for example Android app which will be also synchronized with web and iOS device. User will have one account for all platforms.

The question is the app with this kind of implementation of In App Purchase and Newsstand API will get approved.

Comment: I am sorry. I have added the question.